# How to use square otto bus event post in WearableListenerService?

Tags: android, wear-os, otto

Background: I am adding android wear support to my mobile application and having issues with using otto bus event in the WearableListenerService.

I added a TasksService on my mobile which extends WearableListenerService. Whenever wear app requests for any new tasks, i am trying to post a bus event from the TasksService(ex: bus.post(new TasksEvent.GetTasks()) where i make a HTTP network call using Retrofit and get the new tasks. Once i get the new tasks from the network and posting the response using bus.post again. In TasksService, i have a subscription for the response and send that to wear app.

Issue:

The problem is by the time i make HTTP network call and get the response, WearableListenerService is getting destroyed and subscribe event is not getting called. Can anyone give insights how to use otto bus event in android WearableListenerService ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start a separate `Service` to do the (potentially long-running) work of your HTTP call and response. As you've noted, when you're just extending `WearableListenerService`, the system kills the service when the Wear API interactions are done.

Also, you probably want to move away from using Otto in this case. I've not used Otto specifically, but my experience with other event buses is that they're not a good fit for this situation. They can be a nice shortcut for times when you need to communicate between disparate places in your code, but they need to fit within the Android component lifecycle - which this case does not. You'll probably need to connect a `GoogleApiClient` in your new service and send the data back to Wear from there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped me.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue it's customary to Accept it.

Comment: Sorry.. I am new to Stack overflow. I accepted your answer now.